# Variable default value

Tags: java, variables, default-value

"It is important to point out that the content field of the template is by default set to null (as Java does with all noninitialized object fields upon creation)."

It is from book "JavaSpaces Principles Patterns and Practice"

Here is code:

```
public class Message implements Entry {
  public String content;
  public Message() {
  }
}
```

I wonder if this is true, because I watched somewhere on internet that this is not true?

Comment: Write it up, compile it, run it, use an IDE, debug it.

Comment: Perhaps you should link to the article that claims this is not true so that we can help explain what it _really_ meant.

Comment: @Adam I am not sure of this internet address, maybe I am wrong, I don't remember.

Comment: @Marcelo, you are right, I tried to println uninitialized String and it prints null. But it was confusing me that int default value is 0. kylc explained this below.

Comment: Yes, kylc's answer clearing up that primitive types behave differently is spot on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, this is true, but it may not mean quite what you think it means.  All **object** fields will be initialized to `null` if no value is specified, but primitive types have other default values.  For instance, `int` fields default to `0`, `float`s to `0.0`, and `boolean`s to `false`.

More information on these defaults here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html.

Comment: just to complete: (one of) the reason for this is that a primitive type can not be `null`

Comment: @kylc: Can I explicitly initialize the int member variable value to something like 2, float member variable to 4.4? Likewise initialize String and boolean variables? Is it possible?

Comment: @kylc: I realize that it can be can be done using a constructor, but can it done while declaring itself? Just curious..

Answer (score 5):

It is probably true, but if you really want to be sure that `content` starts as null, then set it explicitly.  (Doing this also makes it more clear that your code intends `content` to be null initially.)

```
public String content = null;
```